# How do I bind a click event to an Infopath form's button using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, infopath, infopath2010

I tried the following but it doesn't work in one particular scenario. It doesn't do anything if there is a dynamic drop-down control in the info-path form.

My code:

```
window.onload = function() {
     window.setTimeout(DoSomething, 1000);
}
function DoSomething(){
$('input[title="ClickMe"]').click(function () 
{
       alert("hello");
});
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are missing closing bracket for `DoSomething` method. If that is a typo then its fine otherwise this will throw error on the page and it will not execute any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DoSomething` is missing its parentheses `()`, which are needed even though it has no parameters. Without them, JavaScript treats `DoSomething` like a variable or property.

As for your drop down question, it doesn't make sense that a true drop down would cause any difference in this code at all because drop down lists should be `select` elements, not `input` elements.

```
window.onload = function() {
     window.setTimeout(DoSomething(), 1000); // <-- Needed parentheses
}
function DoSomething(){
$('input[title="ClickMe"]').click(function () 
{
       alert("hello");
});
```